# Why is a Spark dataframe with 1 large row taking a long time to write?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with just 1 row, but that row is about 1 gigabyte in size. Writing it takes a very long time. My job runs for about an hour because of that, is that normal?

I did coalesce(10) before writing, it didn't help. I think coalesce and repartition shuffle around rows of data, am I right? But in this case there's just 1 row, so the data skew persists anyways.

How do I go about solving this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please share configuration of your driver and executors

Comment: @AmanSehgal I use 1 executor, 4 cores and 32 gigs for driver and executor memory. If I increase the number of executors, the job takes even longer, due to shuffling that moves around 1 gig of data.